# Error multiple highcharts while loading in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm loading multiple charts in a bootstrap carousel, but I get always the following highcharts error:

> Highcharts Error #16
>
> Highcharts already defined in the page
>
> This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded
>   in the same page, so the Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep
>   in mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of
>   Highcharts are included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and
>   StockChart in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js
>   file.

This is what I do in my html:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $numquestions; $i++) { ?>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h2><?php echo "de titel van de question"; ?></h2>
                        <div id=<?php echo "container" . $i; ?>></div>
                    </div>
        <?php
        } ?>

    </div>
    <!-- Controls (CHECK ICONS) -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&laquo;</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

I create the number of items in my carousel.

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var categories = new Array();
var data = new Array();
var chart;

var questionsandanswers = <?php echo json_encode($questionandanswers); ?>;

for (var i = 0; i < questionsandanswers.length; i++) {
    questiontitle = "";
    answers = "";

    // Loop through questions
    var questiontitle = questionsandanswers[i].Text;
    var answers = questionsandanswers[i]['0'];

    createChart(i, questiontitle, answers);
}

// Create the Charts
function createChart(i, questiontitle, answers){
    chart="";
    i++;
    // CHART OPTIONS
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            renderTo: 'container' + i
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: '',

            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,

            title: {
                text: 'Aantal keer gekozen',
                align: 'high'
            },

            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            //valueSuffix: ' aantal keer gekozen'
        },

        plotOptions: {
             bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: 'black',
                    formatter: function() {
                        if (this.y === 0) {
                            return null;
                        } else {
                            return this.y;
                        }
                    }
                },

                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },

        credits: {
             enabled: false
        },

        series: []
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); // Create new chart with general options

    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        // add answers to categories array
        categories.push(answers[i].Text);
        data.push(answers[i]['0']);
    }

    // add categories to x-axis
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);

    chart.addSeries({data:data,name:'Aantal keer gekozen'},false);
    chart.setTitle({ text: questiontitle });

    // redraw chart
    chart.redraw();
    categories = Array();
    data = Array();
}

</script>
```

As you can see I add the charts to the different containers but I still get an error. I know I add multiple highcharts in the same page but I need to ... . How can I fix this that I don't get that error?

Comment: I've seen that error when highcharts.js was included more than once or highstock.js and highcharts.js were included.

Comment: Thanks, that was idd the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've loaded the highcharts javascript in my general layout script as in my view. Which gave me the error that highcharts was already defined in my page ... . Stupid mistake!